# "Vectorized" matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have two matrices x and y, both with dimensions 100x2.  I would like to create a list such that for each row of x and y, I have the matrix t(x) %*% y.  For example, via a for loop:

```
x = matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 5)
y = matrix(rnorm(10), nrow = 5)
myList = list()
for(i in 1:5){
    myList[[i]] = t(x[i, , drop = FALSE]) %*% y[i, ]
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this calculation?  I've tried to figure out how to express this a matrix multiplication but have had no luck.  I've also considered mapply, but it seems as if I'd need to convert x and y to lists of vectors instead of matrices to use mapply, and I'm skeptical that that is the correct approach either.

Comment: I think it would be `Map(function(x,y) matrix(x,ncol=1)%*%y , split(x, row(x)), split(y, row(y)))`

Comment: You should preallocate the `mylist` object which will make your for loop approach noticeably faster. Use `mylist = vector("list", 5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way with `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y) matrix(x,ncol=1)%*%y ,
               split(x, row(x)), split(y, row(y)))
```

Comment: I can't imagine this being faster than a loop though, though it is probably cleaner coding.

Comment: `Map(tcrossprod, split(x, row(x)), split(y, row(y)))`

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten (and possibly slightly speed up) your code with

```
NewList <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) NewList[[i]] <- outer(x[i,],y[i,])
#> all.equal(NewList,myList)
#[1] TRUE
```

or, equivalently,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) NewList[[i]] <- x[i,] %o% y[i,]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Map is the best approach:

```
library(rbenchmark)

x = matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 5000)
y = matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 5000)
myList = list()

loopTest = function(){
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        myList[[i]] = t(x[i, , drop = FALSE]) %*% y[i, ]
    }
}

loopTest2 = function(){
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        myList[[i]] = outer(x[i, ], y[i, ])
    }
}

mapTest = function(){
    Map(function(x,y) matrix(x,ncol=1)%*%y ,
                   split(x, row(x)), split(y, row(y))) 
}

mapplyTest = function(){
    mapply(function(x,y) matrix(x,ncol=1)%*%y,
           x = split(x, row(x)), y = split(y, row(y))) 
}

benchmark(loopTest(), mapTest(), mapplyTest(), replications = 100)
```

This gives me:

```
test        elapsed
loopTest()   10.471
loopTest2()  12.225
mapplyTest()  3.100
mapTest()     2.252
```

However, the loop approach does win on smaller datasets, say with only 5 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the test. So there's no gain in speed with `outer()`, as it seems.